# I need find the smallest odds bet on a single competitior in a single event from a table of bets and create a new column called lowestOdds

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I have data like this:

```
transactionID  EventID CompetitorID  odds 
  1                 1     1           3
  2                 1     1           2.5
  3                 1     1           2
  4                 1     2           8
  5                 1     2           9
```

I need:

```
transactionID  EventID CompetitorID  odds lowestOdds
1                 1        1           2         2
4                 1        2           8         8
```

I need to generate a further column called lowestOdds and populate it with the lowest odds transacted for that competitor in that event.

I created the column first so all I need is the update query.

```
Update tblBets Set lowestOdds= Min(odds) ...
```

How do I run the min function only against bets for that competitor in that event?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Is this Microsoft Access **or** MySQL?

Comment: I am working with both, though I didn't expect that the sql is any different.
Importing into mysql from csv was just not feasible but access was able to do it with ease. I am trying to clean it up first and make derived columns before using a free converter to generate a sql dump and then get it in mysql. I do have about a million records imported before I gave up, so i could work in Toad for mysql or in access

Answer (score 0):

Use a query for this - for events and competitors:

```
Select 
    EventID,
    CompetitorID, 
    Min(odds) As LowestOdds
From
    tblBets
Group By
    EventID,
    CompetitorID
```

- for competitors only:

```
Select 
    CompetitorID, 
    Min(odds) As LowestOdds
From
    tblBets
Group By
    CompetitorID
```

- for events only:

```
Select 
    EventID, 
    Min(odds) As LowestOdds
From
    tblBets
Group By
    EventID
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav,
Does that query give the lowest odds for each competitor? 
If it does how do for a single event?
In this data there will be transations for the same competitor in different events

Comment: Yes thanks for that. It does exactly what I asked aart from putting it in a new column, but I can work with a view for cleaning purposes.

Unfortunately I didt ask the question quite right.
I am now getting the lowest odds accepted on a single competitor, but I need the lowest accepted in a single eventso I can identify the favourite.
Again I am struggling and getting nowhere. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've added the SQL for events only.